# dateFromString: returns nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to cast a NString into NSData but I don't get it...what's wrong?

```
NSString* createAt = @"Wed May 16 06:42:05 +0000 2012";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"];            
NSDate *currentDate = [df dateFromString:createAt];  //returns nil
```

Comment: (1) `stringFromDate` does not exist. What would it do? (2) `stringFromDate:` is the opposite of `dateFromString:`. (3) Using a date formatter is not a cast. (4) You're creating an NSDate, not an NSData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format string is wrong. It should be:

```
@"eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
```

Answer (score 2):

The format and the string do not match.

The correct format is `@"eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"`.